# Pass single rows from a dataframe to predict with a loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I pass the row index using `iloc` and specifying the position using `n`. Instead, how to modify the code to pass the rows from `class_zero`, and print each prediction of it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature 1':X[:,0],
                                  'Feature 2':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3':X[:,2],
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})

y_train = df['Class']
X_train = df.drop('Class', axis=1)
class_zero = df.loc[df['Class'] == 0]

n = 5  #instead of specifying 5 which is where class_zero = 0, I want to pass directly the class_zero from the list I created
#and print for each one

rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
instances = X_train.iloc[n].values.reshape(1, -1)

predictValue = rf.predict(instances)
actualValue = y_train.iloc[n]

print('##')
print(n)
print(predictValue)
print(actualValue)
print('##')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index of rows where class==0 as a list in `iloc()`

Change the class_zero like this:

```
class_zero = df.index[df['Class'] == 0].tolist()
```

And you are doing the reshape wrong. Keep it like this:

```
instances = X_train.iloc[class_zero].values
```

Edit for comment:

```
for n in class_zero:
    instances = X_train.iloc[n].values.reshape(1,-1)

    predictValue = rf.predict(instances)
    actualValue = y_train.iloc[n]

    print('##')
    print(n)
    print(predictValue)
    print(actualValue)
    print('##')
```

Comment: thanks, how can I pass it as a for loop though. That is, on each loop, it passes a value of n rather than all of them in one go